# Database is throwing an InvalidOperationException status of 500 in a MVC Web Application while accessing data from an SQL View

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sql-view

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC Application in which I have an SQL View with five columns and I have the following model for it

```
public class InferredBid
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Market { get; set; }
        public string Term { get; set; }
        public string Bid { get; set; }
        public string Offer { get; set; }
    }
```

SQL View

```
Create VIEW [dbo].[InferredBids]
AS
with numbered as
(
    select id, product, grade, term, bid, offer, termid, row_number() OVER (Partition BY Product, Grade ORDER BY termid) i
    from  dbo.CanadianCrudes
)

select r1.i as Id, r1.product + '/' + r1.grade as Market, r1.term + '/' + r2.term as Term, r1.Bid - r2.Offer [Bid], r1.Offer - r2.Bid [Offer] 
from numbered r1 join numbered r2 on  r1.product = r2.product and r1.grade = r2.grade and r1.termid+1=r2.termid and r1.i<r2.i and r1.term!=r2.term          


GO
```

When I open the page that should render the data from the above SQL view. It just threw me an `InvalidOperationException`

```
<m:type>System.InvalidOperationException</m:type>
<m:stacktrace/>
<m:internalexception>
<m:message>
The 'Id' property on 'InferredBid' could not be set to a 'Int64' value. You must set this property to a non-null value of type 'Int32'.
</m:message>
```

I tried setting the property to int32 but still I have the same issue.

Comment: Also, `int` is just a C# alias for System.Int32. Same with `long` - it's an alias for System.Int64, etc. So `int` and `System.Int32` can be used interchangeably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your code to the following, as it appears that SQL is returning Int64 (equivalent to `long` in C#) for that field.

```
public class InferredBid
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Market { get; set; }
    public string Term { get; set; }
    public string Bid { get; set; }
    public string Offer { get; set; }
}
```